# Why partition is not mounted after installation of ubuntu 12.10 in place of windows 7?

Tags: mount

I have installed ubuntu 12.10 in place of windows 7. Now I can't see my personal data.
Problem is that i'm getting error "can not mount file" while trying to access hard disk under path (GO-Computer)

Please provide your suggestions.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "hard disk under path (GO-Computer)"?

Answer (score 0):

Start by opening **Disks** and try to mount from there. If that fails:

Open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) try `sudo blkid` and take note of the UUID of your partition.

Then run `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab` and add a line like the following one:

```
UUID={your uuid here}   /mnt/Data   ntfs    uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137   0   0
```